# How to test calls to NestJS Logger?

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I have a NestJS project I am trying to add tests for a service. I need to test and verify the calls to the `Logger` to make sure it logs as expected.

My `test.service.ts` file is set up like this

```ts
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger('TestSuiteRepository', { timestamp: true });

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(TestEntity) private readonly repo: Repository<TestEntity>,
  ) {}

  async createTest(createTestDto: CreateTestDto): Promise<TestEntity> {
    const { organization, title, description, questions } = createTestDto;

    try {
      const test = this.repo.create({
        organization, title, description, questions,
      });

      await this.repo.save(test);
      return test;
    } catch (ex: unknown) {
      const stack = ex instanceof Error ? ex.stack : '';
      const msg = ex instanceof Error ? ex.message : '';

      this.logger.error(
        `Failed to create Test! Data: ${JSON.stringify(createTestDto)}`,
        msg,
        stack,
      );
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
  }
}
```

And then I have a `test.service.spec.ts` which is set up like this

```ts
describe('TestService', () => {
  let service: TestService;
  let serviceLogger: Logger;
  let repo: Repository<TestEntity>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TestService,
        {
          provide: Logger,
          useValue: { error: jest.fn() },
        },
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(TestEntity),
          useValue: {
            create: jest.fn(),
            save: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<TestService>(TestService);
    serviceLogger = module.get<Logger>(Logger);
    repo = module.get<Repository<TestEntity>>(getRepositoryToken(TestEntity));
  });

  describe('createTest()', () => {
    it('should successfully create a test', async () => {
      const newTest: CreateTestDto = {
        organization: 'abcd-efgh-ij',
        title: 'My Title',
        description: 'Foo',
      };

      const createdTest: TestEntity = {
        id: '1234-5678-9012',
        questions: [],
        ...newTest,
      };

      jest.spyOn(repo, 'create').mockReturnValue(createdTest);
      jest.spyOn(repo, 'save').mockResolvedValueOnce(createdTest);
      // jest.spyOn(serviceLogger, 'error');

      await expect(service.createTest(newTest)).resolves.toEqual(createdTest);
      expect(serviceLogger.error).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should log and throw an error when repo.create() fails', async () => {
      const newTest: CreateTestDto = {
        organization: 'abcd-efgh-ij',
        title: 'My Title',
        description: 'Foo',
      };

      const createdTest: TestEntity = {
        id: '1234-5678-9012',
        questions: [],
        ...newTest,
      };

      jest.spyOn(repo, 'create').mockImplementation(() => {
        throw new Error('Create failed!');
      });
      jest.spyOn(repo, 'save').mockResolvedValueOnce(createdTest);
      // jest.spyOn(serviceLogger, 'error');

      const result = await service.createTest(newTest);
      expect(serviceLogger.error).toHaveBeenCalled();

      await expect(result).rejects.toEqual(new InternalServerErrorException());
    });
  });
});
```

My 2nd test seems to fail since it throws an error. It's expected to throw an error, but that error seems to prevent the `Logger` from being verified that it has been called. If I slightly re-write that test like this to `spyOn` the `Logger` and encapsulate the thrown exception:

```ts
it('should log and throw an error when repo.create() fails', async () => {
  const newTest: CreateTestDto = {
    organization: 'abcd-efgh-ij',
    title: 'My Title',
    description: 'Foo',
  };

  const createdTest: TestEntity = {
    id: '1234-5678-9012',
    questions: [],
    ...newTest,
  };

  jest.spyOn(repo, 'create').mockImplementation(() => {
    throw new Error('Create failed!');
  });
  jest.spyOn(repo, 'save').mockResolvedValueOnce(createdTest);
  jest.spyOn(serviceLogger, 'error');

  const result = () => service.createTest(newTest);
  
  expect(serviceLogger.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
  await expect(result).rejects.toThrow(InternalServerErrorException);
});
```

I get this error:

```
 FAIL  src/test/test.service.spec.ts (5.105 s)
  ● TestService › createTest() › should log and throw an error when repo.create() fails

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      91 |       const result = () => service.createTest(newTest);
      92 |
    > 93 |       expect(serviceLogger.error).toHaveBeenCalled();         |      
                             ^
      94 |       await expect(result).rejects.toThrow(InternalServerErrorException);
      95 |     });
      96 |   });

      at Object.<anonymous> (test/test.service.spec.ts:93:35)
```

What do I need to do differently to properly test the `Logger` **and** the exception being thrown here?

Comment: Why are you injecting the logger? The component you're testing doesn't get it via DI.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, I've got no idea how else to get it. I am looking for help here and that was kind of me flailing around to try anything. That's why I'm asking this question because I don't know how to get or test the logger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Logger` here is an instance of the [`TestingLoggerService`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/testing/services/testing-logger.service.ts) due to the way that the `Test.createTestingModule()` works. I would expect the logger to properly log the error if it happens, but there will not be anything seen by your spy because there's no dependency injection happening for the logger, so the custom provider `provider: Logger` isn't being used. This is because you set `private logger = new Logger()`. You'd need to use `jest.mock('@nestjs/common', factoryMock)` to mock **just** the logger and otherwise leave everything else alone, if you wanted to actually mock the logger.

An easier (though less type safe approach) would be to do something like `jest.spyOn((service as any).logger, 'error')` so that you can spy on the service's instance of the `logger`'s `error` method.

Comment: I figured my provided `Logger` wasn't working, that was me just experimenting I guess. I'll remove that. So what is `factoryMock` here and what is the result of the `jest.mock('@nestjs/common', factoryMock)` call?

Comment: A large, ugly factory method that provides **all** of Nest's default functionality _minus_ the logger so you can mock that directly. [Read up on jest.mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options). I'd also say, you probably don't need to be mocking the logger, it's probably not adding any value to the test.

Comment: ok, that's good feedback thanks.  I'll skip that to simplify and just make sure it throws an exception